# How to turn off the pager for AWS CLI return value?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cli

I am attempting to utilize the AWS CLI along with a `for` loop in bash to iteratively purge multiple SQS message queues.  The bash script works almost as intended, the problem I am having is with the return value each time the AWS CLI sends a request.  When the request is successful, it returns an empty value and opens up an interactive pager in the command line.  I then have to manually type `q` to exit the interactive screen and allow the `for` loop to continue to the next iteration.  This becomes very tedious and time consuming when attempting to purge a large number of queues.

Is there a way to configure AWS CLI to disable this interactive pager from popping up for every return value?  Or a way to pipe the return values into a separate file instead of being displayed?

I have played around with configuring different return value types (text, yaml, JSON) but haven't had any luck.  Also the `--no-pagination` parameter doesn't change the behavior.

Here's an example of the bash script I'm trying to run:

```
for x in 1 2 3; do 
  aws sqs purge-queue --queue-url https://sqs.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com/<id>/<env>-$x-<queueName>.fifo; 
done
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, Can you share an example? maybe share with us the SQS or the interactive pager?

Comment: Did you try `echo q | aws sqs ...` ?

Comment: Rewrite the `for x (1 2 3)`, options: `for x in 1 2 3`, `for x in {1..3}` and `for ((x=1; x<=3; x++))`.

Comment: `--no-pagination` refers to server-side pagination, for situations where the result of a list command would be too long for the server to respond the full list in a single response. It does not affect client-side pagination.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Just running into this issue myself, I was able to disable the behaviour by invoking the aws cli as `AWS_PAGER="" aws ...`.

Alternatively you could simply `export AWS_PAGER=""` at the top of your (bash) script.

Source: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/4702#issue-344978525

Comment: Nice find on that Github pull request, that was exactly what I was trying to find in the AWS documentation but never had any luck. Thanks!

Comment: As that source mentions, if you aren't into the env var solution, you can also add `cli_pager = cat` to your `~/.aws/config`

Comment: Amazing! finally got rid of the annoying behaviour on my ssm script

Comment: Here's the documentation on this as well as a lot of other useful configuration options: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html

Comment: And if you don't want the extra feed through `cat`, you can just set `cli_pager = ` in your aws config

Answer (score 78):

You can also use `--no-cli-pager` in AWS CLI version 2.

See the "Client-side pager" section here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html

Answer (score 49):

You can disable pager either by exporting `AWS_PAGER=""` or by modifying you AWS cli config file.

```
export AWS_PAGER="" 

### or update your ~/.aws/config with 

[default]
cli_pager=
```

Alternatively, you can enable the default pager to output of `less` program as

```
export AWS_PAGER="less"
```

or corresponding config change.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html#cli-usage-pagination-clientside

Comment: To update aws configuration file, this command can be used: `aws configure set cli_pager ""`.
Append `--profile profile-name` to disable pager specifically for a profile.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the environment variable `PAGER` to `"cat"` to force awscli to not start up `less`:

`PAGER=cat aws sqs list-queues`

I set up as a shell alias to make my life easier:

```sh
# ~/.zshrc
alias aws="PAGER=cat aws"
```

Comment: Nice, this works.  Looks like you can also use `PAGER=""` to achieve the same result. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I am using the aws cli v2 via docker and passing the `--env AWS_PAGER=""` on the docker run command fixed this issue for me on windows 10 using git bash.

I set it up as an alias as well so things work with jq.

How to set your docker env values:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

Example alias:
`docker run --rm -it -v c:/users/me/.aws:/root/.aws --env AWS_PAGER="" amazon/aws-cli`

Comment: you have a typo in first line.  --env AWS_PAGEER=""  two EE.  Otherwise thumbs up!

Answer (score 4):

Inside your ~/.aws/config file, add:

`cli_pager=`

Comment: nice approach! works for me. it should belong to some profile, which i missed in the first step https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html