# ZSH clears terminal and presents command return data

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

When trying to run a for loop or even an `aws list` command in zsh with Oh My zsh, the shell clears the terminal, and I get something like:

```
{
RETURNED DATA
}
(END)
```

I have to enter `q` in order to return back to the original shell and I see my command with no returned data, though the command has run successfully. If I remove ~/.zshrc it works. It seems to be an issue with the Oh My zsh file.

Comment: Maybe it's PAGER settings?. What do you see with `for f in /var/*; do print $f; done` ?

Comment: Yeah that works. It seems to be related to JSON being returned. I was using a `seq 1 10` loop with aws cli which returns JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the pager tip. This resolved it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122188/how-to-turn-off-the-pager-for-aws-cli-return-value 
I added `export AWS_PAGER=""` to .zshrc and it did the trick.