# How to make aws cli quiet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When I am using aws cli commands it adds debug data to its output.
Is there a way to make it quiet?

Here is my use case:

```
# get deployed version
COMMAND="git describe --tags"
aws ecs execute-command --cluster="${CLUSTER}" --task="${TASK}" --container="${SERVICE}" --command="${COMMAND}" --interactive > VERSION
```

The issue is that instead of expected contents of VERSION file (just the version number):

```
0.0.67
```

I have something like that:

```
The Session Manager plugin was installed successfully. Use the AWS CLI to start a session.


Starting session with SessionId: ecs-execute-command-123456789abcdefgh
0.0.67


Exiting session with sessionId: ecs-execute-command-123456789abcdefgh.
```

How can I get rid of the debug data?
I already tried adding `--quiet` parameter (parameter does not exist)
and redirecting error output, none helped.

Answer (score 0):

I can see your post was Nov 2022. By this time aws cli v2 had been already available. I think this is the option you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/66333386/12176490
and in AWS Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html#cli-usage-pagination-clientside

```
In order of precedence, you can disable all use of an external paging program in the following ways:

Use the --no-cli-pager command line option to disable the pager for a single command use.

Set the cli_pager setting or AWS_PAGER variable to an empty string.
```

So at the end of your aws cli command add `--no-cli-pager` .